# Add field to wordpress billing fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to add 2 custom fields to the user billing information in WooCommerce, one for capturing their VAT number and one for the Chamber of Commerce number. These fields need to be displayed during checkout, on the my account > billing address page and also on the WP Admin on the user page so the admin of the website/webshop can check for these values.

I prefer not to use a plugin but to use the child theme's functions.php.

Can anyone please help me with this problem? I looked around on the Wordpress Stack exchange but couldn't find a specific and up-to-date solution for my problem. Also I read the Woocommerce documentation but there it's not explained how to show the custom billing fields on the user admin page in the backend.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using Woocommerce filter `woocommerce_checkout_fields`.

Here is the code example.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields','checkout_extra_fields');
function checkout_extra_fields($fields){
    $fields['billing']['vat_number'] = array(       
        'label'       => __('VAT number', 'my-slug'),
        'placeholder' => __('VAT number', 'my-slug'),
        'required'    => false,
        'clear'       => false,
        'type'        => 'text',
    );

    $fields['billing']['commerce_number'] = array(      
        'label'       => __('Commerce number', 'my-slug'),
        'placeholder' => __('Commerce number', 'my-slug'),
        'required'    => false,
        'clear'       => false,
        'type'        => 'text'
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

Also, You can get the saved values from backend by this code

```
$extra_fileds_vat_number    =   get_post_meta( wf_get_order_id($order),'_vat_number',1);
$extra_fileds_commerce_number   =   get_post_meta( wf_get_order_id($order),'_commerce_number',1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, these fields will then be added to the My Account page and checkout as well? Also they will be auto saved in the DB? And my last question, how can I display these fields in the WP Admin backend on the profile page of that user?

Comment: Please accept the reply, if it is solved your issue.

Comment: Of course I will Nishad, but I'd like to know how to display these fields on the backend on the user profile page, not on the order admin page. The users need to fill in these fields when they want to become a wholesale customer, so the admin of the website/shop need to be able to check these fields (and other billing info) and enable that customer as a wholesale client before that customer can even place an order.

Comment: For adding custom field in user page, you many need to use separate filter. I'll help you to find some solution.

Comment: @Dongen, Please refer below link. I hope this will help you on you issue.  http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't want to be rude, but on the woocommerce my account page the VAT/COC fields aren't showing up. Only on the checkout page. Do I need to add some specific filter to show them?

Answer (score 1):

Altough I didn't want to use a plugin and Nishad's answer is absolutely correct I found a free plugin (after a really long search) that does exactly what I want. It's called **Flexible Checkout Fields** and you can create custom fields that show up on Checkout, Woocommerce my account page and on the WP admin user profile page. I really love it!

So for anyone who encounters the same problem, you might want to try this one!